Getting latex paint overspray off a new shower insert
I was spraying my bathroom right after a new shower insert was installed. I guess some masking blew back and I got latex paint overspray all over the insert. Of course, I didn't realize it until it had dried for a week or so.
I'm really afraid of scratching the white insert and I'm hoping someone has a clever trick to getting it off without damage. I've tried some sponges and brushes with no luck!

What are you calling an "insert"—the surround?  If so, try some Goo Gone Latex Paint Clean Up.

Drops of latex paint on a smooth hard surface can often be scratched off with just your fingernail.

There are plastic or nylon "razor blades" available to install in scrapers to aid in scraping on surfaces that would be scratched by the "real" ones.

Latex paint is relatively easy to remove from a smooth surface. Assuming that this is a plastic or fiberglass shower insert, you can use automotive detailing clay to remove overspray with no risk of scratching. Buy a clay bar kit from your local auto parts store or the Amazon. It should include a bottle of spray lubricant and the clay itself. Follow the instructions.
